# Handling Invalid XML with Nokogiri::XML::Reader

Tags: xml-parsing, nokogiri

I have found the Nokogiri xml reader to be strict with xml syntax so if it encounters an invalid character within the xml, such as a non-escaped ampersand (eg. `<tag> Garage & Driveway </tag>`) will cause an error to be thrown.

So when I use the reader as follows:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Reader(infile).each do |node|
  # does stuff with node
end
```

Throws the error:

```
Entity: line 1056614: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name
            <tag>The & is invalid</tag>
                      ^

transmogrifier/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/reader.rb:106:in `each'
```

With XML such as this:

```
<root> 
  <items>
    <tag>The & is invalid</tag>
  </items>
  <items>  ...  </items>
<root>
```

Midway through parsing a large document. I've noticed Nokogiri::XML::Parser handles this (more) gracefully, and removes all invalid characters, which gives me hope for a more graceful solution.

Ideally, I would love to be able to catch the error and continue with the each parsing (as very few items have invalid characters). Any suggestions on how to handle this gracefully?

Ive noticed you can pass in ParseOptions, but havent had any luck with using those.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from `Nokogiri::XML` to `Nokogiri::HTML`, which is much more forgiving of XML errors, will probably help.